# Visual Studio 2022 - Git (Bitbucket) integration, nowhere to enter password

Tags: git, visual-studio, bitbucket

I have created an app password within my bitbucket account to use with Visual Studio 2022, but I can't see anywhere in Visual Studio where I can set this password to replace the one it already has stored.

If I try to push to a repo it says:

```
Remote: Bitbucket Cloud recently stopped supporting account passwords for Git authentication.
Remote: See our community post for more details: https://atlassian.community/t5/x/x/ba-p/1948231
Remote: App passwords are recommended for most use cases and can be created in your Personal settings:
Remote: https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/
Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
Git failed with a fatal error.
```

Comment: That's not how git works anymore with remote repos. Isn't secure enough. 
You have generate an SSH key on your local device, change the repo remote to use SSH, and import the public key to bitbucket. Here's the link to the docs
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/

Otherwise you can install like git credential manager. Which is a bigger annoyance IMO.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to connect VS 2022 to BitBucket? I'm only seeing options to connect to GitHub or Azure DevOps repositories now.

Comment: UPDATE - I was able to get this to work via git bash. Once my VS project was created, I had to create/initialize a git repository via git bash within the project folder. Once that was done, I closed and reopened VS2022 and my git changes are now able to push to BitBucket. Odd that BitBucket isn't a standard option within VS22, but it can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded Git for Windows which includes Git Credential Manager and was able to get it working, thanks to @dustbuster for suggesting it.